# How to disable CACHE in FORM which loads database values in form fields

Tags: forms, database, caching

I am loading database values in my FORM and seems form is CACHING and loading old data from the database.

I have followed instruction here ([How do I prevent a form from being cached for Anonymous users in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211593/how-do-i-prevent-a-form-from-being-cached-for-anonymous-users-in-d8)) but still old data is loaded in form fields.

Here is my code and would appreciate if anyone can shed light where I am missing;

....

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

// Define form fields.
$form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 80,
  '#title' => t('Your Name'),
  '#default_value' => $result->name,
);

return $form;
}
```

....

Do I have to add 'use Drupal\Core\Cache;' on top of this file?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the linked question the module *Internal Page Cache* was not enabled. If you don't want to disable page caching for all pages, but only for this form page, then add `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger()` before you return the form:

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

// Define form fields.
$form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

$form['name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#size' => 80,
  '#title' => t('Your Name'),
  '#default_value' => $result->name,
);

\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

return $form;
}
```